# javascript setTimeout detail item

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm new to javascript . Can anyone help me explain the setTimeout function . 
Here is my code paragraph .

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    var djs ; 
     function autoFunction(){


        var value = $("p").html();

        value =parseInt(value);
        value  = value - 1 ; 
        if(value  >= 0){

            $("p").html(value);
            //this works 
            djs = setTimeout(autoFunction ,1000);

            //this don't work 
            // djs = setTimeout("autoFunction()",1000);
            //this work but not I want 
            //djs = setTimeout(autoFunction(),1000);

        }else{
            alert(1);
            clearTimeout(djs);
        }

    };
    autoFunction();
 })
</script>
```

I use jquery-1.9.0 , and Chrome .
The Chrome Version is 33.0.1750.146 .
And Sorry for cannot  comment on you,  because the website cann't load jquery from google .

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Comment: In what way does `setTimeout("autoFunction()", 1000)` "not work"?

Comment: The version with `setTimeout("autoFunction()", 1000)` works for me, and there is no reason it should not work. By the way, there is no need for the `clearTimeout`--by the time the code has gotten there, the timer is already finished.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function willl call the `autoFunction` after 1000 milliseconds.

The reason it doesn't work with () is because the argument to `setTimeout` will be the result of `autoFunction()` rather than a reference to the actual function.  After 1000ms, whatever you pass as that first argument will be executed, therefore, it must be a reference to a function - not the result.

Open the console, and type "autoFunction", and the console will print out that javascript.  But type "autoFunction()" and the console will execute that function.  Think of "autoFunction" like a variable that contains a function, instead of a value.

Here are some test cases:

```
 func1 = function() { 
     console.log("Function 1"); 
 }

 setTimeout(func1, 1000); // <-- delays 1 seconds
 setTimeout(func1(), 1000); // <-- no delay, as func1() executes immediately
 setTimeout("func1()", 1000); // <-- delays 1 second, via the "code" option for setTimeout, so long as it's in scope.
```

Per @RobG's comment, some scope clarification:

```
 $(function(){
     func2 = function() { // <-- note the declaration here.  Function stored in a var.
         setTimeout("func2()", 1000);
         // works, because "func2" exists in the global scope, where setTimeout lives
     }

     function func3() {
         setTimeout("func3()", 1000); 
         // fails, because func3 only exists within this $(function() { })
     }
  })
```

Comment: But why setTimeout("autoFunction()",1000), don't work .

Comment: For the same reason `setTimeout("ABCDEFG",1000)` doesn't do anything, because `"ABCDEFG"` isn't a function.  It's just a string, and doesn't mean anything.  `"autoFunction()"` is a string. Whereas `autoFunction` is the name of a function that setTimeout will execute.  And `autoFunction()` isn't the name of a function, it's a command to execute that function right then, and hand the results to `setTimeout`.

Comment: This is incorrect. In fact, you **can** pass a string to `setTimeout` if you really, really want to, although you shouldn't.

Comment: you can past code, sure, but it's certainly not the recommended habit to form for "new to Javascript" people.

Comment: @mainstreetmark Saying something not recommended is entirely different from saying it is wrong and can't possibly work. If you want to say this is not recommended, then say that. Meanwhile, you could provide a hypothesis for why the OP's code `setTimeout("autoFunction()", 1000)` did not work, because it seems as if it should.

Comment: jokes on me, then.  I didn't know that was valid.  After a brief test, I see that it is.  Feel free to provide your own answer.

Comment: @mainstreetmark Meanwhile, your "accepted" answer answers only 1/2 of the question...it omits any answer to the part that asks `//this don't work`. The question doesn't need another answer, it needs one complete one.

Comment: `setTimeout("autoFunction()",1000)` doesn't work because the string is executed as an expression in a global execution context, but *autoFunction* is declared inside the function expression passed to *$*, so not accessible from the global context. Declare it as a global function and it will be accessible (and create *djs* as a global variable when called the first time).

Comment: @RobG, ahh, how obvious, that is actually the correct answer.